# Filling a <select> with the saved option as chosen in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to fill a `<select>` dynamically with the chosen option as first option.

Here is my attempt:

```
<select id= "my_id" name="my_name" size="1" class="my_class">
    @foreach($items as $item)
        @if($selected_item->item_id == $item->id)
            <option selected value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    @foreach($items as $item)
        @if($selected_item->item_id != $item->id)
            <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

`$selected_item` contains the ID of the item in other table. `$item` contains the ID and names of all items.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't work __how__? What's the output?

Comment: @u_mulder the output is the first one on the list

Comment: How do we know which one is the selected option?

Comment: @Thomas That's what $selected_item is for, if it has the same id as $item_id then it's the selected option. That's why there are two loops

Comment: *`$selected_item` contains the ID of the item in other table*. How can you select an item from another table if you are printing this table?

Comment: @apokryfos I pass the info from controller using multiple tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

i) `$selected_item` is an `object` and doest have property `item_id`.

ii) `$items` is an `array` of `objects`.

then following code should produce desired results.

```
<select id= "my_id" name="my_name" size="1" class="my_class">
    @foreach($items as $item)
        @if($selected_item->item_id == $item->id)
            <option selected value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Already tried that one before, it didn't work so I tried to do what I did in the OP, so the first <select> is always the chosen one, and then loop again to retrieve the rest of items except the chosen one. It doesn't work either.

Comment: checkout this http://ideone.com/Etz5c5
I tried to reproduce the same, can you post your couple of records?

Comment: do `var_dump` while printing records.